# Django, is it mandatory to have USERNAME_FIELD?

Tags: django

```
One type of user authenticate with phone number 
Another type of user authenticate with email.
```

So some users don't have phone, and some don't have email.

Can I specify USERNAME_FIELD to be `id` ? or don't have it at all?

Comment: You can make a field `phone_email` for example that stores some sort of unique item, and you thus can "mix" the `phone` and `email`, but yes, you need a unique field.

Comment: you can create a dynamic unique username on every registration

Comment: how about `id` being unique field? @WillemVanOnsem not possible?